# How do I setup redirect for multiple subdomains to different folders

Tags: redirects, mod-rewrite, apache2

So I have 2 sites on this particular server and this is all internal, but when a user goes to websvn for instance, I want them to go to websvn.domain.local and it is going there but it is also redirecting to /phpmyadmin

CentOS 7.1 Apache 2.4.6 all internal domains.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what I have so far for websvn.conf 
Code:

```
Alias /websvn /usr/share/websvn/ 
ServerName websvn.borg.local 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^websvn.borg.local [nc] 
RewriteRule (.*)$ /websvn/ [R=301] 
ProxyRequests           Off 
ProxyPreserveHost       On 
 
    Order deny,allow 
    Allow from all 
     
ProxyPass  /websvn/  http://websvn.borg.local/websvn 
ProxyPassReverse  /websvn/ http://websvn.borg.local/websvn 

 
   Options +MultiViews 
   DirectoryIndex wsvn.php index.html index.php index.cgi index.pl 
    
      # Apache 2.4 
      Require ip 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 
    
    
      # Apache 2.2 
      order deny,allow 
      deny from all 
      allow from 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12
```

Here is my phpMyAdmin.conf

Code:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin 
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin 
ServerName phpmyadmin.borg.local 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /phpMyAdmin/ [R=301] 
ProxyRequests           Off 
ProxyPreserveHost       On 
 
    Order deny,allow 
    Allow from all 
     
ProxyPass           /phpmyadmin/     https://phpmyadmin.borg.local/phpmyadmin/ 
ProxyPassReverse    /phpmyadmin/     https://phpmyadmin.borg.local/phpmyadmin/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
Redirect permanent /websvn/ http://websvn.borg.local/websvn/
```

By the way there some info missing: server type, how you access your web site, mainly.
There lot of way to redirect trafic in apache config.

**PS:** `http://websvn.borg.local/websvn/` is better than `http://websvn.borg.local/websvn`

`http://websvn.borg.local/websvn` add an useless redirect to `http://websvn.borg.local/websvn/`

Comment: Sorry about that. This is running CentOS 7.1 with latest apache 2.4.6.  I main access it using firefox internally.

Comment: Also, will a redirect permanent work with the other subdomains on this server as well?

Comment: if pattern `/websvn/` is found en requested url it will redirect, so if you have a subdomain like `http://{anything}.borg.local/websvn` it will work by the way http://{anything}.borg.local/websvn = http://{anything}.borg.local/websvn/ but with a redirection from websvn to websvn/ so i edited the post to improve the answer